# Shadow in Listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView with an arrayadapter.
for some reason when i scroll the list i get this shadow and when i stop its ok.
thats my code:

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    if(textView.getText() == "royi"){
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }else{
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);
    return rowView;
}
```

}

```
public class Listwithbaseadapter extends ListActivity {

static final String[] MOBILE_OS = 
        new String[] { "Android", "iOS", "royi", "Blackberry", "Android", "iOS", "royi", "Blackberry", "Android", "iOS", "royi", "Blackberry", "Android", "iOS", "royi", "Blackberry",
    "Android", "iOS", "royi", "Blackberry", "Android", "iOS","Android", "iOS", "royi", "Blackberry", "Android", "iOS"};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

why is it happening and who can i fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListView listView = getListView();

listView.setCacheColorHint(0);
```

Comment: did that... its still hapaning...
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#0000">
</TextView>"

Comment: not in textview you want to set in list view   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewmosq"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"/>

Comment: thanks, im new at this.  as you see i dont really use a listview object... so what another xml file will help? who should i tie to the xml file?

Comment: sorry check updated answer. Add this code in Listwithbaseadapter

Comment: Thanks!!!! i only changed setCacheColorHint(Color.parseColor("#0000")); to setCacheColorHint(0); and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

use

```
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setCacheColorHint(0);
```

in your ListActivity.

Comment: Thnks!!!!  im sorry, but parag answer before you did... and i managed to find the answer although it had a littele mistake.  
your answer is totaly correct!

Answer (score 1):

In you xml add following property in Listview

`<ListView android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
...
/>`

it will solve the problem. no need to do it dynamically in the code and if you want to remove the top and bottom shadows when you scroll you can add the following also:

`<ListView 
   android:fadingEdge="none"
   ...
/>`